# Asterisk: how to match following numbers in single pattern

Tags: asterisk

I need to match incoming call extension number in Asterisk dial-plan which can be

- exact
- prefixed with area
- country and area code

If my local extension is 5321879 I can get incoming calls to:

1. 0038515321879
2. 015321879
3. 5321879

how can I match each of those with single pattern ?

is

```
_!5321879
```

usable in Asterisk dial-plan

Does anyone know any other solution than to have 3 different extensions?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. can you try to clarify it a bit meaby?

Comment: @IonutHulub well i need to find if it is possible to get such expression which will catch all 3 possibilities in **Asterisk** or I should make separate extension matching for each of the possibilities.

Answer (score -1):

```
^(01|003851)?5321879$
```

This should do what you're asking for.

Comment: this is something used as regexp. what i need is regular expression in Asterisk dialp-plan. therei slimit of wild chars. and is actually a question for Asterisk i have removed regexp TAG from question.
From Asterisk Documentation:
The letter X or x represents a single digit from 0 to 9.
The letter Z or z represents any digit from 1 to 9.
The letter N or n represents a single digit from 2 to 9.
If you wanted to match all four-digit numbers that had the first two digits as six and four, you would create an extension that looks like:
exten => _64XX,1,SayDigits(${EXTEN})